# How to replace non-zero values as default in data.frame object by row-wise?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have data.frame object that consist of two vectors v1, v2. As you can see from my data, v1 contains 0e+00, I want to assign this values to the row that contains 0e+00. I attempted to do this but I did not get what I expected. How can do this in R? 
However, this is my attempt to do this, but it won't work:

```
res<- apply(data, 1, function(ro) {
  tmp<- ifelse(length(ro[[1]]==0 & !length(ro[[2]])==0),0e+00, ro)
})
```

## reproducible example as follow:

```
v1 <- c( 1e-06,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,1e-07,0e+00)
v2 <- c(4.551651e-38,3.519523e-33,6.316980e-26,8.159048e-34,
        4.935429e-20,4.551651e-38,9.080082e-38)

dat <- data.frame(v1, v2)
```

## My desired output (I did manually here to show how it looks like):

```
DataFrame with 7 rows and 2 columns
         v1    v2
  <numeric>    <numeric>
1     1e-06 4.551651e-38
2     1e-05 3.519523e-33
3     0e+00 0e+00
4     0e+00 0e+00
5     0e+00 0e+00
6     1e-07 4.551651e-38
7     0e+00 0e+00
```

## then I want to cancel out that row contains 0e+00, so final desired output:

```
DataFrame with 7 rows and 2 columns
         v1    v2
  <numeric>    <numeric>
1     1e-06 4.551651e-38
2     1e-05 3.519523e-33
3     1e-07 4.551651e-38
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: `data <- data[data$V1 != 0,]` ?

Comment: @scoa: it did not give me what I expected. Any better idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the entries by using `!=`

```
v1 <- c( 1e-06,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,1e-07,0e+00)
v2 <- c(4.551651e-38,3.519523e-33,6.316980e-26,8.159048e-34,
        4.935429e-20,4.551651e-38,9.080082e-38)

dat <- data.frame(v1, v2)

dat[dat$v1 != 0e+00,]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @scoa said:

```
#show data where v1 equals 0 (0e+00)
dat[dat$v1 == 0,]

  v1           v2
3  0 6.316980e-26
4  0 8.159048e-34
5  0 4.935429e-20
7  0 9.080082e-38

#show v2 where v1 equals 0 (0e+00)
dat$v2[dat$v1 == 0]

[1] 6.316980e-26 8.159048e-34 4.935429e-20 9.080082e-38

#Remove rows where v1 equals 0
dat[dat$v1 != 0,]

    v1           v2
1 1e-06 4.551651e-38
2 1e-05 3.519523e-33
6 1e-07 4.551651e-38
```

Comment: @scoa: Thanks a lot for this quick solution. I can get correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
dat[dat$v1 == 0,][,2] <- 0e+00
dat[dat$v1 != 0,]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution pretty close to what I expected. However, I got accepted the answer from Sergio.

Answer (score 0):

Use grepl function for the second output

```
dat <- dat[!grepl("^0",dat$v1),]
     v1           v2
1 1e-06 4.551651e-38
2 1e-05 3.519523e-33
6 1e-07 4.551651e-38
```

for first output you can use the same function too

```
dat$v2 <- ifelse(grepl("^0",dat$v1),0e+00, dat$v2)
dat
     v1           v2
1 1e-06 4.551651e-38
2 1e-05 3.519523e-33
3 0e+00 0.000000e+00
4 0e+00 0.000000e+00
5 0e+00 0.000000e+00
6 1e-07 4.551651e-38
7 0e+00 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is also very interesting.